# Reading from arraylist to check if it contains username and password

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am creating a login page that reads the username and passwords from a text file in to an arraylist. It will then check the arraylist to see if it contains the username and password. For some reason, I can't figure out why it's not returning true if it contains it. I think the problem is that there are multiple strings in each index but I don't know how to check if it just contains one.
Any help would be appreciated. It is in JFrame GUI.

Login button.

```
  private ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();

  private void loginBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    username = loginUsernameTxt.getText();
    password = String.valueOf(loginPasswordTxt.getPassword());
    if (username.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "No username or password entered.");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            if (users.get(i).contains(username) && users.get(i).contains(password)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Login is successful!");

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Username or password does not match. Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Register button

```
    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)); // instantiate my buffered write and file write also open it in append mode.
    try {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(file);
        int line = 0;
        while (myScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String checkUser = myScanner.nextLine();
            line++;
            if (checkUser.contains(username)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Username already in use, please try another.");
                uniqueUsername = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (uniqueUsername == true) {
            output.write("Usernames: " + username);
            output.newLine();
            output.write("Passwords: " + password);
            output.newLine();
            output.close();
        }
```

Thank you for the solutions so far, I feel like the hash map is the right way to go but I don't know how I would add them all to it.
So far this is what I have to add to the arraylist.
How would I add all of the usernames and passwords to the hash map?
Thank you in advance.

```
  try {

        try (Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            while(myScanner.hasNextLine()){
                users.add(myScanner.nextLine());
            }
        myScanner.close();
        }
}   catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

I have done it!
Thank you all for the help, every comment was very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: How about using a `java.util.Map` with the username as key and password as value?

Comment: I hope this is only an exercise or homework. In a production system, you shouldn't store passwords in plaintext.

Comment: yeah it's homework

Comment: If you can use Map, then see javaguy's answer. But if your assignment requires you to use ArrayList, then your problem is that you don't stop once you find the username & password, but continue to the remaining entries of the ArrayList which don't have the username & password. You need to use `break;` or add a boolean flag to say the username & password were found.

Comment: Can you add the sample data inside the file, how it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong data structure i.e., if you use a List for storing both usernames and passwords, 
you will NOT be able to differentiate which user has set the password, i.e., you can't map(relate) them.

So, what you need is a `Map` (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) which stores data as a key & value pair (like your username and password), so you need to use `Map`, instead of `List` as shown below code with comments:

```
 //declare a Map key is username and value is password
 private Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();

 private void loginBtnActionPerformed(
         java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    username = loginUsernameTxt.getText();
    password = String.valueOf(loginPasswordTxt.getPassword());
    if (username.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                     "No username or password entered.");
            } else {

                //retrive the value from Map using get(key)
                if (users.get(username) != null && 
                users.get(username).equals(password)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                           "Login is successful!");

                 } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                     "Username or password does not match. 
                           Please try again.");
               }
          }
    }
```

You can place the values to the `users` `Map` as shown below:

```
users.put(username,password);
```

Also, to check that if username already exists:

```
users.containsKey(username)
```

Comment: I've never used a hash map before, how do you add the values of the text file in to it?

Comment: try (Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(file)) {
                while (myScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    users.add(myScanner.nextLine());

Comment: Here you have the [Map Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) JavaDoc.
Basically to put a key value pair into it, you use:
`Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("username", username);
map.put("password", password);`
you can then do a `map.get("username");` for example, to get the username object reference back.

Comment: that's what I had for the arraylist

Comment: You can simply use `users.put(username, password)`

Comment: Can you add the sample data inside the file, how it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPasswordField than you should maybe get your password like this

```
/**
 * @return the password
 */
public String getPassword() {

    String password = null;
    if (this.loginPasswordTxt == null) return null;

    char[] buffer = this.loginPasswordTxt.getPassword();
    password = new String();

    for (char c : buffer) {
        password += c;
    }

    return password;
}
```

Your list contains username and password is strange why not using HashMap

So here if i understend well user.get(i) should be concatenation of username + password for this to work cus if you put

```
users.add(username)
users.add(password)
if (users.get(i).contains(username) && users.get(i).contains(password)){
 // never goes true
}

users.add(username + password)
if (users.get(i).contains(username) && users.get(i).contains(password)){
 // should be good
 break;
}
```

best solution is

```
HashMap<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
users.put(uesrname, password);
if(users.get(username) != null && users.get(username).equals(password)){
   // connected
   break;
}
```